# Wake on LAN (WOL) on Mac Pro 3,1 WITHOUT MacOS

Tags: mac, sleep-wake, unix, mac-pro

I've been re-purposing my Mac Pro 3,1 (2008) to be a server using docker and Ubuntu Server 18.04.2. I'm trying to get wake on lan to work, as this is a really power-hungry machine and I would rather not let it run all the time.

Everything I can find shows how to enable WOL with macOS, however I have completely removed macOS and now only have Ubuntu server.

Is there some way I can enable WOL using some sort of bios or single user mode or something like that. Thanks!

Comment: With macOS installed this option is set on OS level. Doesn't Ubuntu provide similar functionality?

Comment: you figured it out? Having the same problem with a proxmox install.